# Add Button between ViewPager2 items

Tags: android

In my android project I've got a ViewPager2 element and
I want to add a button as divider between its items.
What would be the common way to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Viewpager` and `ViewPager2` are libraries that enables user to use swipe feature for fragments. For example, if you have 3 fragments with/without tabs and you want to swipe over them to move from one fragment to another, you will use `ViewPager` or `ViewPager2`.

So you cannot use `Viewpager2` to add layouts/views/elements, you can add Fragments to it using a `ViewPagerAdapter` and the fragment will have the required UI. I am not sure what you want to do exctly but this can be a useful [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2) on `ViewPager2`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My aim is to put a button between every viewpager2 items, like a divider. When I click on that button I want to add another item (to the left or right of the current selected item). The button actually shall add a new ViewPager2 item to the left/right of that selected element.

Comment: Well as I mentioned ViewPager2 is not for this. You have to manage this logic in the ViewPagerAdapter or the activity/fragment that you are putting the adapter in. ViewPager2 only provides the swipe gesture functionality for fragments.